# Почему classList.toggle не работает?

Tags: javascript, toggle

При нажатии на кнопке должен убираться класс и добавляться, меняя цвет кнопки, чего не происходит..
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема ?

```js
const btnqqq = document.querySelector("#qqq");

btnqqq.classList.add("www");

btnqqq.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  btnqqq.classList.toggle(".www");
});
```

```css
#qqq {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
}
.www {
  background: #ffd500;
}
```

```html
 <button id="qqq">fdfd</button>
```

Comment: Опечатка - точка не нужна в классе в тоггле

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const btnqqq = document.querySelector("#qqq");
btnqqq.classList.add("www");

btnqqq.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  btnqqq.classList.toggle("w");
});
```

```css
#qqq {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
}
.www {
  background: #ffd500;
}

.w {
  background: blueviolet;
}
```

```html
 <button id="qqq">fdfd</button>
```